# Align center the Popup child window based on parent window inner height

Tags: javascript

[How to set Popup child window center of parent window for different browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM5Ge.png)

[Please check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xknwb.png)

```
Please check the below code. Tried below code for child popup center.
```

`code`
var new_window;
function winOpen(){
width = window.innerWidth - 100;
height = window.innerHeight - 120;
var top = (screen.height - window.innerHeight) - 10;
var left = 100 / 3;
new_window=window.open('https://www.google.com',"_blank","toolbar=0, help:no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=no,width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ",top=" + top + ",left=" + left + "");
}
`code`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center an element horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: @D-Money - No, Thanks !

Please check - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xknwb.png

Comment: Is the popup an element of the page, or a separate tab / window? If it is a separate tab / window, you do not have access to things happening outside the window as a normal webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can center *elements* inside the DOM in numerous ways, they are too many to list. However, usually it is done without JavaScript (your tag), but rather with CSS.

One way is by setting `display:flex;`, `place-items:center` and `justify-content:center;` on the parent;

Here is an example:

```css
.parent {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #08f;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  place-items: center;
}

.child {
  width: 95px;
  height: 95px;
  background: #0a0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```